# How do I get only the first value for each item in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with product names and each product has 1 or more (up to 5) images. I'm trying to get just the product name and the `first` image, but the way I have it it prints all the images. How do I get just the first one for each?

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

    foreach ($result['images'] as $image) {
     echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];
     echo "\n";
    }

 }
```

Which prints like:

```
 Title: Blah
 Image: http://1..
 Image: http://2..
 Image: http://3..
```

I want to get just

```
 Title: Blah
 Image: http://1..
```

I tried modifying it to

```
echo 'Image: '.$image['full_image_url'][0];
```

but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];


    echo 'Image: ' . $result['images'][0]['image_url'];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Alternatively (if you dont know first index for example)

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

    foreach ($result['images'] as $image) {
        echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];
        echo "\n";
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: echo 'Image: '$result['images'][0]['image_url']; it should be  echo 'Image: '.$result['images']['image_url'][0];

Comment: @devpro `foreach ($result['images'] as $image)` and `echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];`  suggest its `$result['images'][0]['image_url']`. I think its good. Concatenation was indeed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

    foreach ($result['images'] as $image) {
       echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];
       echo "\n";
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get title and first element of image array please try below code :

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];
    echo 'Image: '.$result['images']['0']['image_url'];
    echo "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) 
{
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

    foreach ($result['images'] as $image)
    {
       echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];
       echo "\n";
       break;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index id than you can use like that:

```
foreach ($my_array as $result) {
     echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];
     echo 'Image: '. $result['image_url'][0];
}
```

And alternate is:

```
foreach ($my_array['results'] as $result) {
    echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

    foreach ($result['images'] as $image) {
        echo 'Image: '.$image['image_url'];
        return;
    }    
}
```

Third solution is provided by **@gacek**